# Count deleted records after a DELETE

Tags: sqlite, sql-delete

I try to count how many records will be deleted after a `DELETE` command:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM BOXES
WHERE EXISTS  ( 
    DELETE FROM BOXES WHERE product='25043620' AND Order='0846'
)
```

I get an syntax error near delete, but I can't figure out which is it.

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/changes.html: *This function returns the number of rows modified, inserted or deleted by the most recently completed INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE statement*

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After some digging, I figured out... after

```
DELETE FROM BOXES WHERE product='25043620' AND Order='0846'
```

I ask database for changes with:

```
SELECT changes()
```

and I get how many rows was deleted.

Comment: In a lot of situations this might need to be in an atomic transaction to behave as intended

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you can combine the count and the delete. Do them individually.

Here's and example :-

> Example - Using SQL EXISTS Clause
>
> You can also perform more complicated deletes.
>
> You may wish to delete records in one table based on values in another
>   table. Since you can't list more than one table in the SQL FROM clause
>   when you are performing a delete, you can use the SQL EXISTS clause.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> DELETE FROM suppliers
> WHERE EXISTS
>   ( SELECT customers.customer_name
>     FROM customers
>     WHERE customers.customer_id = suppliers.supplier_id
>     AND customers.customer_name = 'IBM' );
> ```
>
> This SQL DELETE example would delete all records in the suppliers
>   table where there is a record in the customers table whose name is
>   IBM, and the customer_id is the same as the supplier_id.
>
> If you wish to determine the number of rows that will be deleted, you
>   can run the following SQL SELECT statement before performing the
>   delete.
>
> ```
> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM suppliers
> WHERE EXISTS
>   ( SELECT customers.customer_name
>     FROM customers
>     WHERE customers.customer_id = suppliers.supplier_id
>     AND customers.customer_name = 'IBM' );
> ```

This from [SQL: DELETE Statement](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/delete.php)

Answer (score 0):

You could try putting the statement into a loop with the argument as the loops condition and then just let the loop count for you as it increments.

Answer (score 0):

For those who came here for SQLServer - you would use:

```
SET NOCOUNT OFF
DELETE FROM BOXES WHERE product='25043620' AND Order='0846'
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT
```

Im not sure if this works in SqlLite however, would be cool if someone could confirm :)

Comment: This is not usual for SQLite.

Comment: ah thanks @forpas - will modify my comment for SQL Server. Didnt realise this was for SQLLite as it wasnt in the title or description!

Comment: The question was tagged with `sqlite` ;)

Answer (score 0):

I also had this question, but am using the C library. There's a function that gets that for you: https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/changes.html.

I did this...

```
    // using String = std::string;
    // execute: runs the query
    uint32_t Db::executeWithCount(const String& query) {
        uint32_t count = 0;
        if(execute(query, detail::empty_callback, nullptr)) {
            // number of rows affected by most recent INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE
            count = sqlite3_changes(_db);
        }

        return count;
    }
```